# Use Tor for all requests of a Docker Container

Tags: docker, proxy, tor

I have a docker container which sends requests to the internet.
All requests which are sent from the container should be wired trough the tor network. The code which was used to build the container can't be changed.

My approach was to setup tor and use privoxy to forward all http/s requests to the socks port. And then use the docker env vars HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY.

I set up a basic docker image with
Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.11-slim

WORKDIR /app
COPY app.py .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir requests

CMD ["python", "./app.py"]
```

and app.py:

```
import requests


def get_ip_as_json():
    url = "https://check.torproject.org/api/ip"
    response = requests.get(url)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        ip_data = response.json()
        return ip_data
    else:
        return {"error": "Failed to retrieve IP address"}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(get_ip_as_json())
```

Without tor/proxy everything works as expected.
Also just using curl with the proxy works fine:

```
curl -x http://127.0.0.1:8118 https://check.torproject.org/api/ip
```

But when running the docker with the proxy I get the following error:

```
docker run --rm --env HTTP_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8118 --env HTTPS_PROXY=http://127.0.0.1:8118 basic_ip_docker
```

error:

```
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='check.torproject.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/ip (Caused by ProxyError('Unable to connect to proxy', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0xffff98cc4a50>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')))
```

I would be super thankful for some hints!

Comment: Does the proxy requires authentication? and more importantly, check that you can reach the proxy from the container (IP+port)

Comment: The proxy does not require authentication but I think I can't reach the proxy.

Comment: That's your problem :) you need to be able to reach the proxy server, check with telnet and ping and see how to create a route or add something to be able to reach it out

Comment: OMG! Thank you so much! 
Your hint helped me solve it haha. 

For some reason it did not work by providing the proxy via the env params (--env HTTP_PROXY). Instead I had to add them to the `config.json`. 

```
"proxies":
 {
   "default":
   {
     "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8118",
     "httpsProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:8118",
   }
 }
```

Comment: Great to hear! good luck! ;)